# AWS CodeBuild cannot find bash script

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, xcodebuild

I am running a CodeBuild process. I need it to run a deploy script that sits within a deploy folder:

```
-deploy
  |- tools
    - deploy.sh
```

I am able to run `ls $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/deploy/tools/` and see the file, but when I go to run `.$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/deploy/tools/deploy.sh` CodeBuild replies with:

```
/tools/deploy/deploy.sh: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

I have also tried it with `bash .$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/deploy/tools/deploy.sh`

Hints as to another way to run this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct container? This has happened to me before when the image I was using was the wrong container

Also, looking more closely I see that you said that you are able to run `ls $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/deploy/tools/` but when you try to run it with `.$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/deploy/tools/deploy.sh` codebuild responds with `/tools/deploy/deploy.sh: not found`. Notice the different path in the CodeBuild response, as opposed to what you can run yourself?